# Run a SQL query based on certain criteria and delete only x rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I know it's possible to run a query where on submit a single row can be deleted if it matches a certain criteria (e.g `delete from table where id=$id`). What I have is a scenario where when I press submit on the form I want to have a certain number of rows that match a criteria taken out at based on another value.

Say for example `$millevel = 100;` I want to be able to search the cities table for rows WHERE nation='$nation' and then delete how ever many rows that is defined in `$millevel`

Is this possible, and if so, is it possible to do it at random so that it doesn't delete in order, but jumps around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of entries to delete with the `LIMIT` keyword:

```
 $sql = 'DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id='.intval($id).' LIMIT '.intval($maxentries);
```

You can add an `ORDER BY RAND()` to do something random, but be aware about performance (will be slow if you have a big table)

See the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html)

Comment: Okay so I could do something along the lines of $delete = 'DELETE FROM cities WHERE nation='.$nation.' LIMIT '.intval($millevel);

Comment: Eh? I don't understand what you're saying :) Does this response satisfied you or I need to go deeper? If it's okay, mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: I'm clarifying that LIMIT '.intval($millevel) would work as long as $millevel is a number

Comment: Yep, that's it. If `$millevel = 100`, then the query will delete the 100 first entries that `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id='.intval($id)` would returned. (Remove every entries if there's less than 100 entries, of course.)

Comment: So I must be doing something wrong here: mysql_query("'DELETE FROM cities WHERE nation='$othernation' AND capital='0' LIMIT '.intval($maxentries).'"); I know $maxentries is working properly, and I know $othernation is there, and I know the fields are as they should be. The cities aren't deleting though. Any input?

Comment: Check your query with `mysql_query("DELETE FROM cities WHERE nation='$othernation' AND capital='0' LIMIT ".intval($maxentries") or die(mysql_error());`. You don't have to put extra quotes around your query.